# How does beforeSaveAddressInformation plugin

Tags: magento, magento2

I was looking at this post: [Magento 2 Add a custom input field on chackout forrm and save it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51319902/magento-2-add-a-custom-input-field-on-chackout-forrm-and-save-it)

I have tried the same way but I am not sure how this part came

```
$customField = $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes->getFiscalCode();
$shippingAddress->setFiscalCode($customField);
```

Where is this `getFiscalCode`?

It's a Custom AttributeCode.

Answer (score 0):

the `getFiscalCode()` method is an accessor method that is used to identity fields such as the one that is created with the extension attribute `fiscal_code` mentioned in the example.

It is not just extension attributes, but all collection models in magento use the following camel casing structure where for example the column `entity_id` in database table, can be accessed via either `$modelCollection->getEntityId()` or `$modelCollection->setEntityId($valueOfEntityId)`

This is a good read to understand the idea [Magento 2: CRUD Models for Database Access](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_crud_models_for_database_access/)